# How to format a USB or external drive?

Tags: usb, disk-formatting

Using Ubuntu 11.10, how do I format an external or USB drive?

I don't find an option to 'format' when I right click. In the new version, the drives don't come up on the desktop, but instead come on the Launcher.

Answer (score 175):

You can use the disk utility(installed by default) to format the drive. There is an option 'format volume' select that option.

[image]

.

[image]

.

[image]

.

[image]

.

[image]

Comment: And what if I get "Error creating partition table: helper exited with exit code 1: cannot open /dev/sdc: Read-only file system"?

Comment: What's the package name for this application? I don't have it installed on Kubuntu.

Comment: Just for completeness, how to pull up Disk Utility from the command line?

Comment: It looks like it's `gnome-disks` (from the `gnome-disk-utility` package) or `palimpsest`.  See ["How to run Gnome disk utility"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/500549/how-to-run-gnome-disk-utility)

Comment: This is always formatting pendrives with bad permissions. After using this app in Ubuntu 16 and 17 it will be usable for writting only in your computer :s

Answer (score 53):

**Formatting a USB drive (Updated for Ubuntu 13.04)**

Type Disks in Dash

[image]

Click on the little gears to open the sub menu as seen in the image below, and click on Format.

[image]

Once the format window appear, choose the way you want to erase, The type of format, and volume name if you need, and then click on format as shown in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Works also in ubuntu 13.10!

Comment: Hmm, in 14.04 it wasn't giving me an option to select the Type for my USB key (which had a busted HFS+ partition on it).  GParted worked though.

Comment: This is probably installed as `gnome-disks` if you're looking for it from CLI. To install on fedora, do `sudo dnf install gnome-disk-utility`

Answer (score 32):

I would recommend you installing GParted which is quite a powerful tool but still easy to use:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

when you installed and opened it, it should be self-explanatory, otherwise dont hesitate to ask in a comment.

Comment: Just a note: You need to actualize/commit the changes for them to take effect.

Answer (score 26):

You can try the **GParted** program for all your partitioning tasks.

You could search for it in the Ubuntu Software Centre or you could type this in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

With GParted you can format your External HDD partition to ext4, but the partition should be unmounted.

Select your external hard drive from the top right corner (it would be marked as /dev/sdb most probably), then right click on the partition and format.

[image: GParted]

After formatting, click on the *accept button* (it's in the middle of the menu bar) *to save the changes*.

Now you would have successfully formatted your external drive to ext4, and it would show up in GParted as a single ext4 partition.

---

As suggested by hellocatfood, after formatting the drive, one will have to take ownership of it as well. To do that, type this in the terminal:

```
sudo chown yourusername: /media/mountpoint
```

***One more thing-***

Your partition should be mounted in `/media/mountpoint`

**To find the mount point**, run `mount` in the terminal, and locate the line that corresponds to the drive or partition in question. If you have never named (or set the label for) it, it will probably look something like:

```
/dev/sdb1 on /media/bf9a2c45-491a-4778-9d76-47832fe38820
```

**If you have set the label with something descriptive**, it should like similar to:

```
/dev/sdb1 on /media/1Tb Pocket Drive
```

After you have the mount point, run

```
sudo chown hellocatfood: /media/bf9a2c45-491a-4778-9d76-47832fe38820
```

(*hellocatfood* is the name of the user)

Or as suggested by Mik, if the drive name has spaces it will need to be escaped or quoted:

```
sudo chown $USER: /media/"1Tb Pocket Drive"
```

Note also that you dont have to specify your user name here; the `$USER` variable will automatically get your username from the system.

This should give the ownership to the current user, and it would be persistent after reboots as well.

I took help for the permissions part from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1840948

and for finding out the mount point, from http://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2012/06/07/ubuntu-hardware-permissions-how-to-set-ownership-of-drive-or-partition-internal-external-hard-disks/

If anyone has any trouble please let me know.

Answer (score 5):

There's a tool which is called Disk Utility (`gnome-disk-utility`). Just open it by searching in the Dash. It should show all your drives and USB sticks. I think using it is very easy. ;-)

Comment: I just checked. You should indeed be able to format drives with it, and it's called *Disk Utility* in the English version.

Comment: You can't find the gnome-disk-utility from the dash.
For some reason it goes by the name 'palimpsest'... Don't ask why

Comment: For arch users; `sudo pacman -S gnome-disk-utility`. Launch using `gnome-disks`

Answer (score 5):

### On Ubuntu 16.04

Just **right-click** on your USB/External Disk and select **format**

[image]

Enter Name and click on <kbd>Format...</kbd>

[image]

Comment: the only thing I don't like about this UX is it goes into the background and gives you no indication of progress. open the disk utility to monitor progress https://askubuntu.com/a/1003024/453746

Answer (score 0):

script automation way to format SDcard or USBstick into FAT:

`mformat -i /dev/cardDevice -s 32 -h 2 -T <total number of sectors> -v cardLabel`

where:

`/dev/cardDevice` would be `/dev/mmcblk0` for SDcard for example.

`-s 32 -h 2` are the few "standard" but mandatory settings (number of sectors per track and number of heads) for the legacy information inside FAT formatted partition.

`<total number of sectors>` will reflect the length of the partition arranged on the device

`cardLabel` would be the label applied to the partition

if it's necessary to format for **FAT32** - append `-F` flag at the end

don't forget to call `sync` command after the formatting