# How do I format an external hard drive?

Tags: permissions, external-hdd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to format a USB or external drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68809/how-to-format-a-usb-or-external-drive)

I have an external hard drive formatted to ext2 and have no permissions. Can't add files, and I can't look at the file that's on there.

It's called "Lost+Found" and apparently takes up 8.1 GB.

All I need to do is back up some files. So it would be fine to erase whatever files are on the drive.