# Error in transfer data to a pen usb

Tags: storage

when i try to transfer data to a pen usb in ubuntu 12.04, the system give me error. The pen is formated in fat32. sorry the english and thank you for any help.

Comment: Without telling us what the error was it is hard to help you. Try it again; write down the error; open a terminal, type `dmesg` and write down the last dozen or so lines.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the file could be the issue: FAT32 has limits on the maximum size of a file (4GB).

If this is the case, you may want to reformat the USB drive (make a backup copy of the current content **before** doing that!).

Here you can find instructions on how to format a drive:

[How to format a USB or external drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68809/how-to-format-a-usb-or-external-drive)

You could choose NTFS (good choice if you wish to share files with other operating systems
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS)

or EXT2 (if your USB drive id to be used for Linux only
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext2).