# How do I clear everything (data, viruses) from a thumbdrive?

Tags: usb-drive, malware, disk-formatting

Say I used some thumbdrive on a public Windows computer and I copy some data to my Ubuntu computer with it. I cannot be completely sure that the Windows computer was clean, and it might have put something onto my thumbdrive. Is there a way to erase everything on a USB-Stick, even MBR viruses and that kind of off-filesystem stuff?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

You can use *good old Linux tool* `dd` to do this.

To do so:

1. First open a terminal with pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
2. Then type `sudo blkid` in the terminal.
3. Very carefully and closely examine the output.

   ```
   [sudo] password for anwar: 
   /dev/sda1: UUID="63c6fb01-aac4-4d38-b29e-5a5780a98d12" TYPE="ext4" 
   /dev/sda2: LABEL="Main" UUID="A80C1BD70C1B9F7E" TYPE="ntfs" 
   /dev/sda5: LABEL="Work" UUID="01CCB271A80A07E0" TYPE="ntfs" 
   /dev/sda6: LABEL="Edubuntu" UUID="364126ac-01c9-4dd2-ab19-eecc733a9640" TYPE="ext4" 
   /dev/sda7: LABEL="Windows" UUID="5A8C72C98C729EE7" TYPE="ntfs" 
   /dev/sda8: UUID="312d4cd9-21a9-4c0d-aa34-26230e70fa89" TYPE="swap"  
   /dev/sdb1: UUID="E87F-1D12" TYPE="vfat"
   ```

   Look at the last line with `/dev/sdb1`. That is the USB drive which is formatted with Fat (vfat) file system. Note that, the USB drive has only one partition which is named `/dev/sdb1`. If it had other partitions, they would have been named as `/dev/sdb2` ... and so on. ***The USB drive itself is named `/dev/sdb`***, Note that, it doesn't have a `1`, `2` or any number after `sdb`
4. Then execute this command to replace all of the data in the USB drive with  0.

   ```
   sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=1k count=2048
   ```

   I intentionally haven't given the original `/dev/sdb` in the command, so that new users do not accidentally mess up their system. Replace the USB drive name found in step 4 in the above command.

This should give you a clean USB. You need to create at least one partition to use the USB after this operation.

#### Creating partition on the empty disk

To create a new partition on it, You can use `parted` program. I'm giving an example of creating a partition in a complete raw disk. Our USB disk is 2GB (~2048) in size. We assume, it's device name is `/dev/sdb`. You can check your device name with the command `sudo lsblk` (you have to guess the correct device by looking at size and etc).

1. First we need to eject the USB after the last command and re-insert it.
2. Then we need to create a partition table on the disk. We are going to create a partition table of type msdos, sometimes known as Master boot record.

   ```
   sudo parted /dev/sdb mklabel msdos
   ```
3. Then you are adding an empty "primary" partition, which will hold a Fat file system later.

   ```
   sudo parted -a none /dev/sdb mkpart  primary fat32 0 2048
   ```

   We specified the start point (from 0 MB) to the end point (2048 MB), though actually the disk may not have full 2048 MB space, but don't worry, parted will adjust it automatically. Note we are creating a *single*, *primary* partition on the whole disk. But you can create multiple partition on it. *(Though it is not recommended, because Windows will only recognize the first partition)*.

   This newly created partition will have the id `/dev/sdb1`
4. Then finally create a Fat filesystem on the /dev/sdb1 partition by doing formatting.

   ```
    mkfs.vfat -n "Disk" /dev/sdb1
   ```

   We are creating a fat filesystem on `/dev/sdb1` partition with the name "Disk".

That's it. You have now a new clean USB disk with a fat partition.

Note, you can also use the Disk-Utility program to create partition and Format it with Fat.

### Using Disk-utility

1. Press <kbd>Super</kbd> key and Type "Disk utility" in it.

   [image]
2. In the Disk utility window, Select the USB drive in the "Peripheral devices" section.

   [image]
3. You may need to unmount the drive first.

   [image]
4. Then click on the "format drive" button

   [image]
5. Select partition table type from the new window. Select "Master boot record".

   [image]
6. After you created the new partition table. The disk utility window will look like this

   [image]

   Click on "Create new partition" button.
7. Select "Partition type" and optionally type a name for the partition.

   [image]
8. The partition will be created within 4-5 seconds and you will have a clean USB disk afterwards.

   [image]

### Using Gparted

1. First you need to install gparted, if you haven't done so yet. You can install it by clicking this link : [gparted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted) [image: Install gparted] or using this command in a terminal

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gparted
   ```
2. Then open gparted by typing "gparted" in the dash. To open dash, press <kbd>Super</kbd> key which also known as "Windows" key.

   [image: opening gparted from dash]
3. Then select the USB device from the drop down menu in right. It should be like `/dev/sdb`, `/dev/sdc` etc. **Please take special care for not to select `/dev/sda`, because it is the device your OS is installed**. You should only select it, if you know what are you doing.

   [image: selecting right device]
4. After selecting the USB device, (which is in my system, `/dev/sdb`) , see whether any of it's partition is mounted. You can see a key icon in the mounted partition entry and the mount point of that partition.

   [image: mounted partitons]

   Unmount any partition mounted partition on that device. To unmount, select the partition → Right click → Select *unmount* from the menu.

   [image: unmount the mounted drives]
5. Then going to gparted menu → *Devices* → select *Create partition table* to overwrite and create a new partition table on the selected device.

   [image: create a new partition table]
6. A new window will be shown Warning you to the action going to be done. The default partition type is "msdos" and I strong suggest you not to change it, if you do not know. Also check another time that, you indeed selected the right device. Then Click *Apply* button.

   [image: Warning]

   After clicking Apply button, the device will be absolutely empty. No partition and no data.

   [image: Empty device]
7. Then  select the unallocated space → Right Click → Select new to create a new partition.

   [image: new partition]

   In the create new partition dialog box, select *Create as* "primary", File system as "fat32" and click on the *Add* button. Optionally, you can also give a name to this partition.

   [image: Create file system]
8. After you click **Add** button, gparted will show you a preview of the device if you apply the changes. There will be a light green tick mark icon in the toolbar. You need to click that icon to apply change. There is also an **Undo** button, you can use it, if something goes wrong at any step.

   [image: Apply changes]

   After applying the changes, gparted will show you a message saying "All operations have been completed successfully".

   [image: success message]

Now you are done with it.

### Using new Disk-utility (12.10)

Ubuntu 12.10 is now equipped with a new Disk utility. It uses new `udisks2` program as backend.

1. First open the new Disk-Utility by typing "Disks" in the Dash. Bring the dash by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> key

   [image]
2. After opening the Disks *(former disk-utility)* program. Do these

   1. Select the externel disk
   2. Unmount the disk if it is already mounted.

   [image]
3. Then select the partition and delete it by pressing the "Stop" play icon.

   [image]

   Repeat this step if you have more than one partition on the disk until all partition has been deleted.
4. After all partition has been deleted, the disk will now only contain Free space. You can now create a partition by clicking the small `+` icon.

   [image]
5. Select the type as "FAT", give a label and push the "Create" button to create a partition.

   [image]
6. Your disk is now containing a partition. You can mount the partition by pressing the "Play" icon. You can directly browse the location of the mounted drive by clicking the link with label "In use, Yes"

   [image]

You're done.

Comment: @Anwar: note that from 12.10 "Disk Utility" has become very simplified, losing all disk management functions. So you may want to add a *gparted* option for the future ;)  Great job!

Comment: WOW! this answer was like somebody asking how do I kill a roach and getting "Take this here bazooka and 10 missiles and..."

Comment: Like the memory stick switching

Comment: Can you clarify step 4 of the command line instructions? It gives a hard coded block size and count but the example doesn't state the  overall disk size. Obviously, people will have to change these params for their own disk.

Comment: How do I set the right blocksize & count for the dd command for my sized usb stick?

Comment: That block size doesn't matter much, actually it is clearing filesystem information from the very beginning off the disk. 1k * 2048 is equal to 2 MB. You could increase the size. Partition step actually creates the new file system. So, no net to worry. @matt

Comment: See the above comment, @scroller

Comment: More command-line ways of seeing your devices:
`df` and `mount | column -t`

Comment: @AnwarShah on the section "Creating partition on the empty disk", on the second step, my Ubuntu 14.04.4 complains by saying: Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab. Evenso I continued with all the steps, I got the same complain in step 3 and in the last step I got: /dev/sdb1: Permission denied. How can I update the /etc/fstab ??

Comment: @Mencia Don't know why that happens. I assume, you're not using `sudo` or in the meantime the disk has been ejected. You can try with other options such as with `gparted`

Comment: @Anwar When I ran your command, it's returning: `2097152 bytes (2,1 MB, 2,0 MiB) copied, 0,524652 s, 4,0 MB/s`

Comment: Excellent post never gets old!

Comment: @Anwar the count parameter in the command is wrong. I think it shouldn't be required but I'm not sure

Comment: The answer that used dd was able to erase a GPT format ISO install image that I had written to a USB stick, but could not remove with GUI disks tool. Worked a treat!

Comment: If you cannot get the new gnome Disks utility to delete partitions on a thumb drive with MBR partitioning, use dd to write some zeros to the first portion of the device as Anwar described at the top of his excellent comprehensive answer. This will trash the MBR enough that you can coax Disks into formatting the now "unknown" extent of the drive as FAT32 or the like.

Answer (score 14):

If you want something utterly and irrecoverably gone, `shred` is a pretty good option.

```
shred -f -n 5 /dev/sdX
```

where `sdx` is your thumbdrive should probably do the trick - it overwrites the whole drive 5 times (change `n` to a suitable number) with random data.

You can find the path to the thumbdrive with `fdisk -l`.

Comment: Very helpful! I usually use `shed -vzn 3 /dev/sdX`: `-v` for verbose, `-n 3` for overwriting it 3 times, and `-z` to write zeroes at the end to hide shredding.

Answer (score 6):

Open terminal

Do

```
lsblk
```

Something similar appears on your screen:

[image]

Suppose your USB drive is sdb with 4 GB memory

Then do

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=2M count=2048
```

In this way you overwrite your entire pendrive with zeros. Everything including any possible viruses and malware will get deleted.

Here `/dev/sdb` portion is extremely important and you need to be extra cautious.
For example, if you put `a` in place of `b` in `/dev/sdb` then your entire hard disk will get written by zeros instead.

Here I gave `count=2048` as my pendrive size is **4GB** and since block size created here is **2MB**, so  **2 MB x 2048 = 4096 MB = 4GB**. Replace **2048** with your suitable value.
Also if you want you can change the block size to whatever you want.

now do

```
fdisk -l
```

The output is something like this

[image]

Here you confirm your current pendrive memory size.

Next you have to create partition table. We will do that with **parted** tool.

In terminal type the following:

```
parted
select /dev/sdb
```

Label it as GPT type parition table

```
mklabel gpt
```

Make default unit size from MB to GB

```
unit gb
```

Finally create the partition table:

```
mkpart /dev/sdb 0GB 3.7GB
```

Here I did **3.7GB** because actual free space of my pendrive is 3.7 GB. Do replace it with your own value.

Next view the final result

```
print
```

The whole thing will be similar to the following:

[image]

Press `q` and put <kbd>enter</kbd> to come out of **parted** prompt.

Now it is time to create a file system. We will be crating the universal file system **fat32**. 
Alo we will be using **mkfs** command to do it.

Type the following in terminal

```
mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb1
```

Now you have a brand new pendrive free from all viruses and malware

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=1k count=2048
```

The script given above only erases the partition table and not the whole disk which is what the OP was requesting.

To erase everything off the disk and setting all bits to zero

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=4M iflag=nocache oflag=direct
```

Explaination of the extra options:

Removing "count=2048" removes limitation to 2048 bytes so dd can perform on entire disk.

bs=4Mb - bs is block size and so this will do the erase in 4Mb blocks, which is quicker than 1k.

iflag and oflag will try to disable buffering, which is not needed for a constant stream.

Then follow the instructions as outlined above to partition and format the disk.

To find the disk letter, open a terminal and run:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/messages
```

Then plug in the flash drive and the disk letter will be revealed!

Substitute the disk letter for X in /dev/sdX

This will blank all data on the disk!

Answer (score 1):

You can format the drive to ensure all data on it is nuked. See [How to format a USB or external drive?](https://askubuntu.com/q/68809/18612) for details on how to do this.

**WARNING: this *will* erase all data on your drive!** Be sure you won't be deleting anything important on your flash drive before trying this.

Comment: This doesn't quite match the question (which I think asks to erase the entire device, not just any one partition as the link instructs). However, I think in general it is sufficient - if you really want to nuke the file allocation table as well you can use dd to copy from /dev/zero or similar onto the whole device (/dev/sdX rather than /dev/sdX1, which is the first (and usually only) partition). As above, be careful.

Answer (score 0):

Windows virus files in a pen drive are visible in Linux. Just delete all the files that you do not know of. Check all the folders to be sure. I have been using this technique successfully since a long time. This way, you can even retain your data.

Comment: For "autorun" type files this is true, but some malware could have made the USB bootable with some mischievous code outside the partition. Or extra scary - if it re-wrote the drive's firmware with it's own commands - not even dd'ing over the entire drive would erase that. Fun fact - usb flash drives, and even microSD cards, have tiny embedded microprocessors/microcontrollers (that cost around 20 cents) with their own firmware that reads & writes the data, keeping track of  which flash chips have gone bad, swapping good ones for bad, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This brute-force force will wipe the partition table completely by overwriting with zeros, leaving you free to re-partition with your chosen tool:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M count=1
```

Be very sure you get the right output device, not some internal disk drive! Recovery from an error will be very difficult. After writing, I would remove and re-insert the stick.

**Source:** https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2319295