# How to format a USB drive?

Tags: usb-drive, disk-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to format a USB flash drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22381/how-to-format-a-usb-flash-drive)
>   [How do I clear everything (data, viruses) from a thumbdrive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185815/how-do-i-clear-everything-data-viruses-from-a-thumbdrive)

How to format a pen drive in Ubuntu?
I have this pen drive which I made bootable using some other system (OS).
But I need to format it from my Ubuntu 12.04. Please guide me.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

## Method #1  (The Graphical Way)

Open **Disks** program from dash:

[image]

Then choose your device from left. Make sure you have selected at least one volume, and click on **format** as below:

[image]

---

## Method #2  (The Command-Line Way)

In case you can't get your device formatted from **Method #1** try this way.

1. Open the Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>)
2. List your block storage devices by issuing the command `lsblk`
   Then identify your pen drive by it's SIZE. In my case its `/dev/sdb`

   [image]
3. Erase everything in the pen drive **(OPTIONAL)**:

   ```
   sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=4k && sync
   ```

   Replace `/dev/sdb` with your corresponding device.  This will take some time. It will pretend to stuck. Just be patient.
4. Make a new partition table in the device:

   ```
   sudo fdisk /dev/sdb
   ```

   - Then press letter `o` to create a new empty DOS partition table.
5. Make a new partition:

   - Press letter `n`  to add a new partition. You will be prompted for the size of the partition. Making a primary partition when prompted, if you are not sure.
   - Then press letter `w` to  write table to disk and exit.
6. Format your new partition.

   - See what is your new partition with a command `lsblk`
     In my case it is `/dev/sdb1`

   [image]

   - Issue the command below to format the new volume:

     ```
     sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb1
     ```

     Please replace `/dev/sdb1` with your corresponding device.
   - Eject the device:

     ```
      sudo eject /dev/sdb
     ```

Comment: @Naveen Dude, what theme/version of ubuntu are you using(I know it is irrelevant question, but I liked it)..

Comment: @BharatSoni: http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/MediterraneanNight+Series?content=156782

Comment: Why is the formatting process when done via the terminal window so damn slow (the USB stick I'm using is only 8 GB in size)? I've been sitting here for well over 10 minutes now and it's is still not finished. Why is that? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Coming back here in 2020 and it still works :) Thanks !
Also patient part is way too long in my slow laptop

Answer (score 6):

You can try the application called **Disks Utility**. It's a very handy utility which should let you format the disk, among other things. You can find it by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and typing the name, or going to **System > Administration**, or I guess typing the name in unity dash.