# USB flash drive stuck in RO after DDing ISO

Tags: partitioning, usb-drive

**After I used `dd` to make a USB drive from an Ubuntu ISO, I am unable to format it for normal use.**

I ran:

```
sudo dd if="ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso" of="/dev/sdb" bs=4M
```

In order to create a bootable USB drive.

However, after I was done with it, I wanted to format it as FAT32 and use it like a normal USB drive.

No problem, should be easy, right? **WRONG**.

I have tried:

- Using the included Disks application to format it. It threw an error about corrupt GPT tables and wouldn't give me an override option.
- Using Gparted the erase the current partition table and write a new MBR table [completed successfully]
- After that I created a FAT32 partition spanning the entire volume, and remounted. [Showed up in Files, good so far]
- Attempted to copy a file to it. It thre an error saying the medium was read-only.
- Erased the partition table again in Gparted and this time created an NTFS partition spanning the entire disk. [Same RO error when attempting to copy a file onto it]
- Repeated the procedure trying this time with EXT4 [Same RO error]
- Repeated procedure trying a GTP table instead of an MBR table. {Same error]

Finally, I tried running:

```
sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb
```

And remounted. Still the same error. Keep in mind that I remounted it after formatting it each time.

## I am at a total loss. Has `dd` bricked my USB drive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't really be sure which of the things I did fixed it, but it turns out that something must not have been synced.

Simply rebooting the computer fixed the issue. **However** I did try plugging it into a different Ubuntu system and it didn't work there either. So it was definitely something I did that fixed it.

---

**For anyone else facing this issue**, I would recommend running these commands to make sure it is usable again:

```
sudo dd if="/dev/zero" of="/dev/sdX" bs=1M count=10 #Replace "X" with your USB's letter
sudo reboot
```

Comment: If that is the solution you have found for your problem, then maybe  you should mark your own answer so that this question could be classified as solved.

Comment: @CristianaNicolae -  Please reverse your downvote. There is a two-day waiting period before I am allowed to mark it as the answer.

Comment: @CristianaNicolae lighten up a little.

Comment: @Android Dev - Sory, the downvote was not my doing. But I have upvoted the answer. I hope this helps .

Comment: The last command to reboot isn't a bad idea, but it's not necessary. You can simply just format the USB stick with your tool of choice after zeroing just the first couple MB of the USB device.

Comment: @b_laoshi - So one would think. But I had to reboot after running those commands before I could write to it again

Comment: @AndroidDev, sudo partprobe /dev/sdb probably would have done it for you if the stick wasn't mounted when you ran dd. If I had to hazard a guess, the device may have been mounted before you ran dd. The dd command did its job, but the previous mount still had a "hook" on the device. In that case, a reboot might be necessary.

Comment: There definitely is a bug in Nautilus which makes Nautilus think a thumb drive's partition is read-only or mounted read-only when it's not. I experienced this many times on different machines after first dd-ing over a thumb drive and then adding a partition table + partition again. Writing to it (with normal user permissions) on the terminal always worked when I tried.

Answer (score 1):

#### using fdisk can be good solution(Be careful not to use wrong drive)

Find your device/disk name:

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb      8:16   1  15.2G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   1   564M  0 part /media/user/pendrive
└─sdb2   8:18   1    31M  0 part
```

unmount all of mounted partition 
then you wand to select whole partition so `/dev/sdb`

```
$ sudo umount /dev/sdb1
```

then use fdisk to create a partition and format to specific filesystem 
Be careful here in selecting disk

```
$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdb
```

then you can use m for help
create a partition table we use DOS partition so `o` then you can print partition table with `p`

```
Command (m for help):o

Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0xd745b93f.

Command (m for help):p
Disk /dev/sdb1: 564 MiB, 591396864 bytes, 1155072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos 
Disk identifier: 0xd745b93f
```

then create new partition using `n`
you can hit enter for default choice of one primary partion or choose according to given option

```
Command (m for help):n
Partition type
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended (container for logical partitions)
Select (default p): 

Using default response p.
Partition number (1-4, default 1): 
First sector (2048-1155071, default 2048): 
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-1155071, default 1155071): 

Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux' and of size 563 MiB.
```

here your default partition is Linux you can change by typing `t` and select `c` for FAT32

```
Command (m for help): t
Selected partition 1
Partition type (type L to list all types):c
Changed type of partition 'Linux' to 'W95 FAT32 (LBA)'.
```

or you can use `L` to list all the type and select your choice 
Then finally you can conform format and quit using `wq`

```
Command (m for help): wq
The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.
```

Now you can remove unplug and plug again 
You can see new drive try writing by making folder & file
Now it must work.