# How to format the unallocated USB drive and make it as Fat32?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, gparted, usb-drive, format

I'm not able to format my USB as stated [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198065/how-to-format-a-usb-drive) and while following these steps :

```
sudo su
fdisk -l
df
umount /dev/sdb1
mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb1
```

my bootable USB was changed to Unallocated format and it's current status is:

`lsusb |grep 4082`:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1976:4082 Chipsbrand Microelectronics (HK) Co., Ltd.
```

`lsblk |grep sdb`:

```
sdb      8:16   1   3.7G  0 disk
```

I have used Gparted, but was not able to fix it.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Your link has quite a lot of ways to do that! Can you be a bit clearer about what you did / what went wrong (in particular error messages) please?

Comment: @Sridhar: Why did you remove the acceptance?  Anything wrong that I should know about?

Comment: Badblocks shows an error while repairing my friends USB@Fabby. Could tell me to fix by using codes which can I repair from Bootable USB to Normal USB? Please

Comment: This is not how this site works: My original answer is still valid, so please add the acceptance ☑ back.  If you would have a [New question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) you can always ping me in the chat room and I'll help you if I can. (I'm only a Vorlon: not a god; I don't know everything)

Comment: @Fabby Surely I'll do, but accepting means the answer is valid.  But it's not working for me Fabby, so please `Answer my question with an another answer ` Let the answer be there, I mean answered. May be it  can work for others. So please Answer once a again. I don't like to dodge. Perhaps it might works for you, Don't Mistake me.

Comment: Sorry, you must have misunderstood me: Clarifying my answer... Please read [the revision](http://askubuntu.com/posts/661173/revisions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*It looks like* your 4GB USB stick is broken. To ensure no one uses a **destructive test** and just copy-pastes the stuff without reading the explanation, you have to type the next command all in lower-case.

> **WARNING**
>          Never use the `-w` option on a device containing an existing file system.  This option erases data! If you want to do write-mode testing
>   on an existing file system, use the `-n` option instead.  It is slower,
>   but it will preserve your data.

So to be absolutely sure it's broken (*or not*) do a:

```
sudo BadBlocks -w -s -o /tmp/BadBlocks.log /dev/XdY
```

Where `X` and `Y` are `s` and `b`

#### If you get errors while executing the BadBlocks command: the USB stick is irreparably broken.  Throw it away and buy a new one.

And if it would give you no errors, you're in luck: just re-format with `gparted` but create an `msdos` partition table first.

*Sorry to be the **very likely** harbinger of bad news*.

Comment: Let me try this and I'll do accordingly @Fabby

Comment: It worked for me @Fabby

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal, `sudo -i` to become root.
Run `fdisk` or `parted`, delete all partitions, create a new one. Use the `fat32` option for type.
Run `mksfs -t fat32 /dev/sdb` (assuming you haven't moved your USB).
Done.

If that doesn't work, consider providing details as suggested above. Sometimes `cat /dev/zero >/dev/sdb` will remove corrupted stuff from USB.

Comment: Can't able to fix it , a little more explanation is needed @Mark