# Format thumb drive with unneeded bootable iso

Tags: format

How do I erase/format thumb drives with installation iso on them? I saw a posting explaining this a few days ago, but I can't find it now.Does disk utility remove boot loader?Seemed to work on the one I formatted,but dont know how to verify.It shows a single empty partition now.Am I done?Dont have windows mackine to fix it on.Only Ubuntu 16.04.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a USB drive?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/198065/how-to-format-a-usb-drive)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/198065/how-to-format-a-usb-drive

Answer (score -1):

Follow these Steps:

1. In windows, open elevated command prompt (i.e. command prompt with admin privileges).
2. Type "disk part" in the elevated command prompt to open the disk partition utility.
3. Type "list disk" in the disk partition utility to display the available disk drives and find your usb drive number.
4. select your usb drive by using the command: "select disk"
   for example if your disk is disk 1 then type "select disk 1".
   It should say "disk 1 is now selected."
5. Type "clean"
6. Type "create partition primary".

That's it. done. your usb is now available to use.
Note that this USB will now be formatted and will not contain any data on it.

You can verify this by opening the disk management utility in windows. (to open just type "disk management" in search bar of windows 10 and open the "Create and format hard disk partitions" utility.

Your USB drive should be displayed as a single primary partition.