# How to format my usb stick? 'No space left on device'

Tags: usb

```
~ lsblk
NAME           MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda              8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk  
├─sda1           8:1    0 215.9G  0 part  /
├─sda2           8:2    0     1K  0 part  
└─sda5           8:5    0   7.7G  0 part  
  └─cryptswap1 252:0    0   7.7G  0 crypt [SWAP]
sdb              8:16   0 149.1G  0 disk  
└─sdb1           8:17   0   149G  0 part  /media/oren/7B78-51A7
sdc              8:32   1  14.3G  0 disk  
├─sdc1           8:33   1   1.3G  0 part  /media/oren/usbdata
├─sdc2           8:34   1     1M  0 part  
├─sdc3           8:35   1   244M  0 part  
├─sdc4           8:36   1   1.5G  0 part  /media/oren/Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS amd64
└─sdc5           8:37   1  11.4G  0 part  /media/oren/casper-rw
~ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=4k && sync
[sudo] password for oren: 
dd: error writing '/dev/sdc': No space left on device
3753907+0 records in
3753906+0 records out
15376000000 bytes (15 GB, 14 GiB) copied, 1539.51 s, 10.0 MB/s
```

The above is exactly what I did and I am getting an error. The tutorial I follow is this one - [How to format a USB drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198065/how-to-format-a-usb-drive)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was told it's expected. it filled my drive with 000000

```
sudo hexdump /dev/sdc
0000000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
*
```

I will continue with the guide now.