# Why does mkfs fail with 'Read-only file system'?

Tags: read-only, fat32

I'm trying to format a pen drive using `mkfs`, but it fails with: *Read-only file system*. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
$ sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb1

/dev/sdb1:
 setting readonly to 0 (off)
 readonly      =  0 (off)
$ umount /dev/sdb1
$ sudo chmod 777 /dev/sdb1
$ sudo mkfs -t vfat /dev/sdb1
mkfs.vfat 3.0.13 (30 Jun 2012)
mkfs.vfat: unable to open /dev/sdb1: Read-only file system
```

What should I do?

Comment: poss dupe http://askubuntu.com/q/185815/46312

Comment: Some pen drives have a readonly/readwrite switch. Have you checked it? Also, after issuing the `mkfs` command, could you please run `dmesg | tail` and paste the output inside your question? Thanks!