# Flash drive not writable after removing bootable OS

Tags: usb-drive

I followed [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/185827/185480) to wipe out the bootable OS from my flash drive. While the bootable was removed, the drive remained unwritable.  I then tried following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/47547/185480) to make it bootable but couldn't:

```
$ sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o uid=$(id -u) /dev/sdb1 /mnt/
Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.
```

How can I make my flash drive writable again?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before, and its probably related to a partition table or MBR problem. Likely, one of those things wasn't configured right and now the hardware is denying you access.

Since you're working with NTFS, jump on a Windows machine and format it again and see if that fixes it.

Unless you know what you're doing, always use a graphical bootable USB writer, and always format USBs back to normal using OS utilities. DD is a low level bit-by-bit operation that can mess with the internal structure of the drive.