# How can I partition a flash drive after wiping it? "you may need to update fstab"

Tags: usb, usb-drive, fstab

How do you update `fstab` after destroying the original file? I am trying to completely overwrite a pendrive with zeros, then create a partition of arbitrary size to store data with no room for viruses.

1. `fstab` was fine, for starters.
2. I ran `dd` on the flash drive, to fill it with zeros. It was full, within about 2 kilobytes.
3. I removed the flashdrive and re-inserted it, hopefully I ejected it first, I don't remember.
4. I ran some commands in the terminal to place a partition on the USB drive. I'm not sure if they worked, or not.

   ```
   sudo parted /dev/sdb mklabel msdos
   sudo parted -a none /dev/sdb mkpart  primary fat32 0 2048
   mkfs.vfat -n "Disk" /dev/sdb1
   ```

   Somewhere among the above steps "you may need to update fstab" messages started appearing.
5. I installed GParted to check on or fix the partition, but could not see the USB drive.
6. Other undoctored pendrives function normally.

I was using [How do I clear everything (data, viruses) from a thumbdrive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185815/how-do-i-clear-everything-data-viruses-from-a-thumbdrive) as a guide.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more info than that. Please [edit] and describe *why* and *how* the "original file" was "destroyed". Which original file? What do you intend to achieve, etc. Creating partitions is unrelated to fstab.

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved. There was a drop-down button in the upper right-hand corner in Gparted that allowed the usb-drive to be displayed, so it could be partitioned. Worked like a charm.