# Why am I getting Input/Output errors with ADATA USB drives?

Tags: partitioning, usb, gparted

I have an HP computer with Ubuntu 18.04. I was copying some stuff to a USB drive. During the copy, I accidentally pulled the USB out. Now the issue is that I get an input/output error whenever I plug in the USB.

I have tried rebooting multiple times. It is not a recent case. I have 2 USBs with the same issue and both USBs are of ADATA. Both had the same issue as I was copying something from Ubuntu and after the copy, I was getting a message of 'Writing to Disk'. I pulled it out anyway and it never worked for me again.

I don't think that the issue is related to the kernel as I have plugged the USB in different computers running different OS but the error is the same in all the cases. My kernel 4.18.0-22-generic

I tried to fix it using GParted but the same issue. When I load up the details of the drive from GParted I get the output shown in the screenshot. I tried to add a new partition table but it just hangs up on me and gets stuck.

Can anyone explain what is going on?

[image: Input/Output Error during read on /dev/sdb]

Comment: Have you rebooted your computer since the incident?

Comment: Multiple times. It is not a recent case. I have 2 USBs with the same issue and both USBs are of ADATA. Both had the same issue as I was copying something from ubuntu and after the copy, I was getting a message of 'Writing to Disk'. I pulled it out anyway and it never worked for me again.

Comment: Have you updated the kernel recently? Have you tried using an old kernel? What computer are you using? (I have a ThinkPad that has persistent USB problems with new kernels. I have to use a 4.x kernel to use USB.)

Comment: I have an HP computer. I'm currently on Ubuntu 18.04. I don't think that the issue is related to the kernel as I have plugged the USB in different computers running different OS but the error is the same in all the cases. My kernel 4.18.0-22-generic

Comment: Since you're having the same problems with different computers and operating systems, I suspect the drives are dead. If they're within [warranty](https://www.adata.com/en/ss/prowar/), try contacting the manufacturer for replacement.

Comment: Well, I kinda had that idea already. But can you like to explain to me in a bit depth for educational purpose that what's going on?

Comment: If no other method works and you have given up on the drives, you may want to try dd-ing those as a last resort (at your own risk). Check this out: https://askubuntu.com/a/185827

Comment: Thanks for the response @CluelessNoob but that doesn't work either. It gets stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're having the same problems with different computers and operating systems, I suspect **the drives are dead**. If they're within [warranty](https://www.adata.com/en/ss/prowar/), try contacting the manufacturer for replacement.

---

You're having an issue using a couple USB drives. It could be a problem with the drives themselves or with your computer. You've ruled out a problem with your computer by rebooting and trying the drives with other computers.

Most likely something electrical is broken that prevents them from writing new data, which is why you can't reformat. It sounds like you pulled the drives when they got stuck "writing to disk" so the problem probably occurred before, not as a result of, your pulling them out.

Since you have two ADATA drives with this problem, you could be dealing with fakes, a bad batch, QA problems, or bad luck. If ADATA replaces them and you have no further problems, it was probably a bad batch. If you have problems with the replacements, QA problems and bad luck come into play.

Unfortunately, storage devices fail. There's not much anyone can do about it aside from backing up and purchasing from historically reliable manufacturers who honor warranties quickly and without hesitation.

Comment: As promised!  **:-)**