# how to erase an iso i wrote on a USB drive?

Tags: usb, iso, drive

i'm on ubuntu 21.10 and i have downloaded ubuntu 13.04 iso and written it on a USB drive. as it's not working I would like to remove it. but how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I clear everything (data, viruses) from a thumbdrive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185815/how-do-i-clear-everything-data-viruses-from-a-thumbdrive)

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is repartition the thumb drive using your chosen disk utility (gparted or even fdisk -- be careful with fdisk, it has no safeties!).

Once you've done that, you can reformat the new partition(s) as if the drive were new.

Comment: If dd was used to write the ISO, then random data is where the partition table is and most partition tools will not work. Reset USB flash that was dd'd to make it usable again, reuse
https://askubuntu.com/questions/939230/formatting-a-usb-stick-unable-to-operate-usb/939266#939266 & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Re-use_the_pendrive & 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216152/usb-disk-read-only-cannot-format-turn-off-write-protection  Then you can use gparted to partition flash drive.

Comment: Pretty sure I've used gparted "new partition table" function to accomplish this, but I'm not at my home computer (nor do I have a Live USB I want to erase or a spare thumb drive to use for testing).  But it sounds like you need to VTC as duplicate.

Comment: Then again, I don't make a habit of using dd to write ISOs to thumb drives...