# USB drive not recognized after Erase Disk

Tags: usb-drive

I was trying to create a bootable USB to install Lubuntu using **Startup Disk Creator** and I accidentally tapped on the "**Erase Disk**" option.

Now Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't seem to read my USB drive anymore. I tried using **GParted**   but it doesn't seem to recognize it either.

Comment: It might be useful to see the dmesg output as you try different operations on you drive. Unplug your drive, open a terminal. Plug your drive back in and type dmesg into the terminal. Look for messages related to your drive to find out what the problem might be.

Answer (score 12):

You may have lost the partition

1. Open `Disk Utility` from **Dash** and select click on the partition that you would like to change, or on the **unallocated disk space** that you will be using for a partition. If the disk space is currently unallocated, it will be labeled "**Unrecognized**" in the `Disk Utility`
2. Click the drop-down menu next to "**Create Partition Table**," and choose "**Master Boot Record.**" Click the "**Create**" button at the bottom of the window.
3. Click "**Create**." You will see a warning reminding you that this process will remove any existing data on the partition. If you are sure that the data on the partition (if any) has been backed up, click "**Create**" again.
4. Enter your `root password`. The label for the hard drive partition will change to "**Unallocated Space**." Click it.
5. Click the drop-down menu next to "**Create File System**" and click "**NTFS**."
6. Type a label for the partition, if you would like to use one.
7. Click "**Create**." You will see a warning reminding you that this process will remove any existing data on the partition. If you are sure that the data on the partition (if any) has been backed up, click "**Create**" again.
8. Enter your root password. The NTFS partition is now created.

Read more: How to Create a NTFS Partition in Ubuntu | eHow.com http://www.ehow.com/how_5781942_create-ntfs-partition-ubuntu.html#ixzz28PnKfwqV

Comment: A great description on how to do so can be found [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/69129/94457)

Answer (score 1):

- This is no longer a problem with the **Startup Disk Creator** in Ubuntu **16.04 LTS** and newer versions.
- But Ubuntu **14.04 LTS** is still supported. I suggest that you use another tool in that version, for example the built-in **Disks** alias `gnome-disks` or some other tool, for example **[mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)**.
- You can use **Disks** or **[mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) to wipe or restore** a damaged USB drive or memory card,

  - [wipe='overwrite with zeros'](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe) (will remove the partition table) or
  - [restore='restore to a standard storage device'](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe#mkusb_version_12_alias_dus) with an MSDOS partition table and a FAT32 file system.

Answer (score 0):

Search for *GParted* in the Ubuntu Software Center and click on the button that says <kbd>More Info</kbd>.

This will show you the GParted Partition Editor screen in the Ubuntu Software Center and at the bottom of this screen is a section called *Optional Add-ons*. Put a check mark in the checkboxes to the left of the three GParted add-ons that are listed below, and click the <kbd>Apply Changes</kbd> button to install:

1. Device-mapper Software RAID support tool (dmraid)
2. Guess PC disk partition table, find lost partitions (gpart)
3. Read/write NTFS driver for FUSE (ntfsprogs)<sup>**1**</sup>

Then try formatting the USB flash drive in GParted again.

[image: Ubuntu Software Center]

<sup>**1**</sup><sub>The Read/write NTFS driver for FUSE is called ntfs-3g in Ubuntu 14.04.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You should simply open Disk creator as though you want to make a startup disk,it will be showing your USB.

[image: The Disk Creator window]

if your disk is listed,then click Erase disk and provide permission, this should fix your USB.
I hope it helps.