# error formatting pendrive

Tags: usb-drive, format

In Ubuntu 12.04 using disk utility while formatting, there was an error

> Error creating partition table: helper exited with exit code 1: Error calling fsync(2) on /dev/sdc: Input/output error

I tried to format even using windows failed and showed up "Windows coudn't format". How can I fix this?

Comment: Your USB stick is broken.

Comment: maybe you could try this **sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M count=40** from [this thread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/help-me-i-cant-format-my-usb-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted)

Comment: @OluDoug **NO!** That will wipe `/deb/sdb`, not `/dev/sdc` which is the required device!

Comment: yeah specify your flash disk not that exactly or gparted

Comment: That `dd` command will wipe it as in it will **WIPE IT** - be careful... The command needed is likely to be `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=1M count=40`. It think this will write zeros to the first 40 bytes of the drive.

Comment: alternatively use gparted

Answer (score 1):

Using [Gparted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gparted/) may of help - install it, open it, and you should be able to reformat the disk once you have unmounted it.

You can do this and other options by selecting the drive in the menu at the top right, and then right-clicking on the partitions.

[image: Picture of Gparted]

Comment: Gparted also has some [add-ons](http://askubuntu.com/questions/196667/usb-drive-not-recognized-after-erase-disk/200874#200874) that may help in case there is a problem formatting the drive, for example because there is an encrypted volume on the drive.