# Backspace key is not working In Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: keyboard, 13.04

The backspace key is not working. <s>And How I can Format of USB Drive in 13.04.</s>

Thank You Ubuntu Developer Team for Making Beautiful OS.

Comment: One question only please.  For format USB see [How to format a USB or external drive?](http://askubuntu.com/q/68809/107450)

Comment: You can use the (ALT + Left) i hate it and tried to change it from keyboard shortcuts but i can't !
can anyone help me to change it ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/289535/bring-back-backspace-keyboard-shortcuts-on-nautilus-and-thunar

Or you can use the (ALT + Left)

Answer (score 0):

If it is just the backspace key you need, there are other alternatices that to downgrade to an older version. Please check out this
[Bring back `BackSpace` Keyboard Shortcuts on nautilus and thunar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289535/bring-back-backspace-keyboard-shortcuts-on-nautilus-and-thunar?answertab=votes#tab-top)