# Bring back `BackSpace` Keyboard Shortcuts on nautilus and thunar

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys, thunar

I want to use the "BackSpace" button as a shortcut key on nautilus. I want to return to the previous folder whilst browsing the Home folder, just like windows 7.

Also I want the same thing while using Firefox, In a way that when I press the shortcut key I will return to the previous web page.

Comment: I can't imagine what is motivation to remove very popular hotkey from app for everyday use.

Answer (score 77):

**For Firefox and Nautilus:** You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>  to go back instead of Backspace.

**For nautilus 3.6** to bring  backspace functionality  you need to add this:

```
 (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Up" "BackSpace")
```

under

```
~/.config/nautilus/accels
```

And then restart nautilus by

`nautilus -q` or `killall nautilus`

In **Thunar** you have to add

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/open-parent" "BackSpace")
```

to

```
~/.config/Thunar/accels.scm
```

Comment: Does it work for you? 

`; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Up" "BackSpace")`

For me, its not working.

Comment: I restarted :( It still is not responding to BackSpace. I think it is not referring that file. Because, even after changing that file, I am able to use Alt + Up

Comment: Please remove the comment. this one -> `;`  use only `(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Up" "BackSpace")`

Comment: Aaah... How could I miss that. Spent two hours this morning. I didnt uncomment. :( Thanks @Achu :)

Comment: Sorry. I didnot ask this question. So I upvoted it.

Comment: It gives me ("syntax error near unexpected token `gtk_accel_path'")

Comment: Thank you alot for showing how to add backspace again to Nautilus! :D :D

Comment: How can I make the addition you are talking about?

Comment: I did what you asked me to do, but still no change. Is this working for others?

Comment: Thanks. Since it is not possible to "bind" both Backspace and Alt+Up to the same (I'm actually quite used to the Alt+Down/Up instead of Enter/Backspace when using only the keyboard), but as a workaround you can also change Backspace to do `"<Actions>/ShellActions/Back"`.

Comment: Aaaaaaah!! its working! sigh of relief! :D thanx a lot

Comment: Is there a documentation for this ? So may be we can find much more information.

Comment: Is not "up" is "back", back is the last directory.
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Back" "BackSpace")

Comment: I think now the shortcut for nautilus is **`Alt`** + **`↑`**

Comment: Not working on Fedora 34

Comment: I had this configuration, it worked. Now something has changed and it doesn't work. Anyone has the same problem?

Answer (score 6):

For Firefox

Open firefox, type in `about:config` in address bar, press enter

Search backspace, should return 1 entry, `browser.backspace_action`

Right click on the value > modify & change from 2 to 0

Answer (score 5):

**for thunar**

Just as I thought, I should have written backspace in a different way. This is how I tried:

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/open-parent" "BackSpace")
```

And it worked.

Comment: Still gice the following error:
("syntax error near unexpected token `gtk_accel_path'"

Comment: @Tareq: Are you using Thunar or Nautilus? Ubuntu comes with Nautilus by default...

Comment: I am using Nautilus.

Comment: @Tareq: well, what I wrote is for Thunar... Did you try Achu's answer?: http://askubuntu.com/a/289540/815

Comment: Yes, But it didn't work, I don't know how to make the addition, or how to write on the Read-Only file (accels).

Comment: maybe you need root access? for example, if you are using gedit to modify the text file, then press alt+f2 and type "gksudo gedit" then open the file and edit it.

Answer (score 5):

Is not "up" is "back", back is the last directory.

```
echo '(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Back" "BackSpace")' >> ~/.config/nautilus/accels
```

Comment: Indeed this is the only one that worked for me.

Comment: Correct - this is proper one for "back', up is parent directory not back. Also note that at least in nautius 3.10 (14.04, trusty) backspace is auto binded to up so one would need to manually edit the file.

Answer (score 5):

2020 - For Nautilus 3.30.5 (on Debian Buster and Gnome 3.30.2)

Based on [nautilus-backspace](https://github.com/riclc/nautilus_backspace), you need to install [nautilus-python](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NautilusPython) and then place a python script in `~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions/`.

Install `python-nautilus` using this:

```
sudo apt-get install python-nautilus
```

You may need to create the directory as well.

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions
```

Now, navigate to the newly created directory:

```
cd ~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions
```

Download the script:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/riclc/nautilus_backspace/master/BackspaceBack.py
```

Finally, restart Nautilus using:

```
killall nautilus
```

Answer (score 2):

To make Nautilus go back like in old times, with the Backspace key, do this:

```
echo '(gtk_accel_path "/ShellActions/Up" "BackSpace")' >> ~/.config/nautilus/accels
```

Comment: @Jorge Castro: you may need to add **<Actions>** to the proposed command: `echo ' (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Up" "BackSpace") >> ~/.config/nautilus/accels`

Answer (score 2):

2019 - For Nautilus:
Based on [@riclc/nautilus_backspace](https://github.com/riclc/nautilus_backspace) repo, I wrote a shell script to install the necessary packages and scripts to bring back this function. I use it with Fedora 30, but the script would work for distros that using `apt` and `pacman` too.

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/7aman/backspace-up/master/install.sh | bash
```

Comment: I tried manually adding the function in accels file and didn't work, I reviewed the code of this before run, saw nothing nasty, and IT WORKED. Thx, you saved me time.

Answer (score 1):

For Debian 11 (based on above information):

```
sudo apt install python3-nautilus

mkdir -p ~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions
cd ~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions

wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/riclc/nautilus_backspace/master/BackspaceBack.py
```

Open the downloaded script for editing:

```
gedit BackspaceBack.py
```

Change lines in the downloaded script as below:

```
"#!/usr/bin/env python"
->
"#!/usr/bin/env python3"

"app.set_accels_for_action( "win.up", ["BackSpace"] )"
->
"app.set_accels_for_action( "win.back", ["BackSpace"] )"
```

Kill and then start manually:

```
killall nautilus
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Thunar:**

This problem has haunted me since the `gtk_accel_path` method stopped working around Ubuntu version 21.10. I'm running `thunar` version 4.16.10. I think I have a solution using `autokey-gtk`:

###### Install autokey

`sudo apt install autokey-gtk`

Open the **AutoKey** application, click **New**, then **Script**, and then I named it **backspace_for_parent** (your choice). Replace `# Enter script code` with the following:

```
win_class = window.get_active_class()
win_title = window.get_active_title()
if win_class == 'Thunar.Thunar' and win_title.startswith("/"):
  keyboard.send_keys("<alt>+<up>")
else:
  keyboard.send_keys("<backspace>")
```

(The second `startswith` condition above was needed to allow normal backspace when renaming files or setting the name of a new folder.)

Then, below, for **Hotkey**, click **Set**. Click **Press to Set** and hit <kbd>backspace</kbd> and then click **OK**.

Finally, at the top, click **Save**.

Now, in Thunar, hitting the <kbd>backspace</kbd> key opens the parent folder!

This is slightly suboptimal in that it uses an external application, but **AutoKey** is fantastic and it's already part of my daily workflow, so nbd from my perspective.

Hope this helps someone.

Inspiration taken from:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/491868/126708