# In Ubuntu 13.04 backspace button in nautilus not working?

Tags: nautilus, nautilus-actions

PC: Acer Aspire E1-571
OS: Ubuntu 13.04 amd64

I want to downgrade my nautilus file browser in ubuntu 13.04 and i have tried the SoluOS patch but not satisfied. I just want to install nautilus 3.4 . Any Help
    Thanks in Advace.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just the backspace key you need, there are other alternatices that to downgrade to an older version. Please check out this
[Bring back `BackSpace` Keyboard Shortcuts on nautilus and thunar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289535/bring-back-backspace-keyboard-shortcuts-on-nautilus-and-thunar)