# Bring BackSpace back to nautilus (3.18+) once and for all!

Tags: command-line, gnome, keyboard, nautilus, shortcut-keys

With regards to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289535/bring-back-backspace-keyboard-shortcuts-on-nautilus-and-thunar) question, the solution provide to get `backspace` for going back in nautilus does not function any longer. I would like to know if there is a functioning workaround for nautilus 3.18.4?

With "going back in nautilus" I me to go up the path, i. e. from `~/.config/nautilus` to `~/config`.

Neither

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Back" "BackSpace")
```

nor

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Up" "BackSpace")
```

in `~/.config/nautilus/accels` and a subsequent `killall nautilus` does the trick.

**EDIT:**

As can be found in [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/38fx19/how_to_set_the_shortcut_to_go_up_in_nautilus/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34716643/accels-file-for-nautilus-on-fedora-23) thread, Nautilus (since 3.15.4) no longer uses `GtkAction`, but `GAction`. A fact not known to me. Is there a way know how to edit `GAction`, without patching it as proposed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/910168/set-nautilus-up-action-to-backspace)?

Answer (score 6):

### Workaround

1) Install [Nautilus Python](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NautilusPython)

(`apt-get install python-nautilus`)

2) Download `Backspace-Back.py`  from [Nautilus-backspace](https://github.com/riclc/nautilus_backspace) and put it here:

`~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions/`

(you might have to create this directory first)

3) Restart Nautilus (`killall nautilus`)

Comment: this forum is for ubuntu, but in fedora the "extensions" is here:  /usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions/
And the package is installed like this:
sudo dnf install nautilus-python

Worked like a charm for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

### Nautilus Shortcuts

You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Right</kbd> to move through your location history.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Left</kbd> has the same functionality as <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

Similarly, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Down</kbd> move your location up and down the *directory branch* visible on the address bar.

**Example**:
[image]

In the example above <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Up</kbd> would move you to `/etc/`.

Likewise, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Down</kbd> would move you to `/etc/apache2/mods-available/`.

Comment: Thank very much for your fast and long answer, A.B. There is no way to get only Backspace working? I ask since I find the proposed solution rather unhandy to use.

Comment: See my **edit**.