# Custom Shortcut to Navigate for Nautilus > 3.20

Tags: keyboard, nautilus, shortcuts

As you know from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/696901/621427), steps of adding custom shortcut were changed and there is an example to open terminal using shortcut in Nautilus with new steps, but I want to create a custom shortcut to bring back (return the previous folder) using "BackSpace" like [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/289540/621427):

(gtk_accel_path "/ShellActions/Up" "BackSpace")

In summarize, I don't want to run any executable file, just I need commands to navigate. How can I managed to this?