# Formating a USB stick with ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, partitioning, usb, unity-dash

I know there's a few relevant questions answered but when I try to format it through disk utility the only answer I get is:

```
"Error synchrinizing after initial wipe: Timed out waiting for object (udisks-error-quark,0)
```

I'm new to Linux, had no problem with Debian, Ubuntu seemed even friendlier in the start but seems I can't do a simple thing like formatting a usb stick. I know that some of you will tell me to download Gparted or something but since Ubuntu by default has a disk utility that does the job it should work, shouldn't it?

Is something wrong with my dash? Is it something fixable or something missing? When a utility is already there it should work or at least know why it doesn't. Installing and using something else is not a good solution.
Formatting is so simple and easy on Debian...

Comment: you can try gparted

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to format a USB or external drive?](http://askubuntu.com/q/68809/107450)

Comment: This is a bug report, and hence off-topic. Hopefully, the linked possible duplicate question is useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

This has been reported as a bug, you can check it out here -
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks/+bug/1059872

you can mention that this bug affects you (at the aforementioned site, i.e.), it'll help give the bug greater attention.

you can always use gparted for formatting a disk. 
to get gparted, you can use the software centre or enter the following command in the terminal

> sudo apt-get install gparted

choose your device, unmount it and then right-click to open a menu. within the menu you'll find a 'format to' option, use that to format it to whichever file format you wish to use, and click on apply.

That should work out perfectly.

Comment: Thank you Projjol, this is a bug as you mentioned which is reported and confirmed since Oct'12 but it still exists at 13.04 as I read... Nice going ubuntu developers!

Comment: Indeed, it's been on Ubuntu's bug list for a while and it affects 72 people, but no major development on that front has taken place. I guess, if more and more users confirm that they're affected by it, it'll get more attention.