# Wipe usb flash drive ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, usb

I have made a bootable USB drive with Ubuntu installer and now I can't delete Ubuntu from it. I tried to use GParted and erased the partition table, made a new ms-dos partition table and formatted the drive as FAT32. Now the name of the drive is still Ubuntu 13.04 amd64 *and a couple of files and folders from ubuntu installer are still there*(eg: wubi.exe, boot and others). I can't delete them because it is read-only. I also tried the following:
open terminal

> sudo fdisk /dev/sdb
>   command: n
>   partition type: p
>   partition number: 1
>   **Now, the minimum value of the first sector is 2048** instead of 62 (the drive has 62 sectors /track)
>   Tried with 2048 as first and all remained the same as before.
>   I need urgent help, any command or thing that might help. Preferably not stuff like Gutmann wipe :)

Comment: I used sudo shred -v command. and wiped it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a USB or external drive?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/68809/how-to-format-a-usb-or-external-drive)

Answer (score 4):

**Note: make sure that you have no needed data on the USB, because this is not reversible.**

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo umount -l /dev/sdbx
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdbx
```

Replace x with your device ID.

Make sure that you format the drive after that.

Comment: sudo shred -v i guess it should work

Answer (score 0):

open disks, unmount your usb stick, format it, done
worked for me

Comment: used sudo shred -v now, 3 passes random wipe. As I said, I even erased the partition table and didn't work. Probably created some kind of hidden partitions I could not reach, formatting didn't work. Also I could not anyway do that because my only option was to eject it, I couldn't mount/ unmount it because it had no table format seen by the system

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem after using a flash drive as an ESXi boot drive. I finally solved it by using the GParted live CD. Nothing else worked for me.