# How to format an external drive to ext4 in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, ext4, format

In Ubuntu 13.04 the Disk Utility has been renamed to Disks and has a completely new interface. Using this new version of Disks I want to format my external hard drive to ext4, but the [answers to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68809/how-to-format-a-usb-or-external-drive) already posted refer to an old version of Disks.

I only have two options when formatting, neither of which is ext4:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to do this?