# Format USB drive using mformat?

Tags: 12.04, usb-drive, format

I have tried many different things to try to format my USB drive, but none of them work... how might I do this using the `mformat` commands? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mformat is only for formatting floppy disks. This should help you formatting your USB drive:

https://askubuntu.com/a/69129/188545