# usb drive is not detected on 12.04 LTS

Tags: usb-drive, detect

I have 15GB Kingston Pendrive. And it is not detected in Ubuntu and remain hung up in Windows.

`sudo fdisk -l` output:

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1   976773167   488386583+  ee  GPT

Disk /dev/sdb: 15.5 GB, 15479597056 bytes
64 heads, 32 sectors/track, 14762 cylinders, total 30233588 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xe31d9cb0

Disk /dev/sdb doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `/dev/sdb` in the above output is your USB drive. If so, it does not contain valid partitions and thus needs to be **formatted**.

This post here on Ask Ubuntu has all the details on [how to format a USB drive](https://askubuntu.com/a/69129/215352).

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to @drc it looks like /dev/sdb is your USB drive and the partition table has been damaged.

I would advise installing gparted

1. [creating a new partition table](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-create-partition-table) on the device
2. [create a new partition](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-create-new-partition)create a new partition
3. [Format partition](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-format-partition) (If using Windows/Linux probably FAT32)]

*Please note, by doing this you will loose the data on the drive