# How do I format an usb to ext4 to use it on Ubuntu without without sudo permisions?

Tags: usb, permissions, ext4, accounts

I use Ubuntu in a machine I own and in a machine I only have standard user permissions ( not admin). Is there any way to format a usb to ext4 and make it work (file ownership problems) if I cannot run sudo commands on the second machine?
Ideally the solution would work on any other Ubuntu/Linux with whatever kind of account.

Comment: You can do that. See more here : http://askubuntu.com/questions/68809/how-to-format-a-usb-or-external-drive

Comment: Disks application will do that.

Comment: It seams I did not put the question clear enough. If I do a normal format then the pendrive user will be root, so I will not have permissions to read/write on it, not will I be able to change through sudo chown. And If I format it and I click on take ownership of the file system then only the user that formated has read/write access. What I want is for all users to have read/write access like with FAT or NTFS.

Comment: @Garoe I would edit your question to clarify that.