# ISO writing to USB doesn't seem to work, how come?

Tags: usb, iso, burning

I've been trying several times to burn an ISO file to my USB, even with Unetbootin, on Ubuntu it doesn't seem to work at all, how come when I download the software that it suggests me to use, and it doesn't works how to fix that issue?

Even if I try to reboot my pc it gives errors that it doesn't reads the USB?

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING?

Comment: @rene I did find kicking an old computer of mine got it to sop making bad noises but that's separate :)

Comment: I ´am not shouting, just used the bigger words, sorry if it seems to be shouting, my apoligy

Comment: @Tim Kicking also fixes such oddities as `Failure to Boot`, `Controller Errors`, `Fan Failure`, `Keyboard Stuck`, and a host of others ;)

Comment: @rene wanted him to reply and realise what he'd done (and maybe edit) fixed now.

Comment: What is the size of `.iso` image? what is the partition table of usb stick it formated fat32, ntfs etc? and what is the capacity of that usb stick? provide more information

Comment: In any case, `dd if=image.iso of=/dev/sdX` should do the trick.

Comment: Formatted as fat 32 as always capacity is 32 gb

Comment: and size of an `.iso`?

Comment: I recemtly installed ubuntu on my pc, but can´t run the windows any more, and the disk utility of my pc is long gone, doesn´t like to burn or read any longer,lol

Comment: this sounds like a different question... what's the size of an `.iso` image that you're trying to burn?

Comment: the size is about 7 gb at the most

Comment: Do you need to be able to edit the content of the ISO (create, delete, edit files)? Or using the USB drive as a CD / DVD to which the image was burn enough?

Comment: Have you tried to use the Startup Disk Creator that comes with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

By default this is how it's made and look like:

**FAT** = *Maximum file size is 2 GB*.

**FAT32** = *Maximum file size is 4 GB*.

**NTFS** = *File size limited only by size of volume*.

As you can see this is the support of the file/image size that supported by each system/partition table.

So, if you're planning on using files larger than 4GB it is recommended to use NTFS nowadays. [How to format a USB or external drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68809/how-to-format-a-usb-or-external-drive)

Comment: Much obliged will format it as ntfs like a cd or dvd is, thanks

Comment: I'm not sure a installation USB should be NTFS... I was told to do it FAT 32.

Comment: well @Tim actually try to burn Win7 .iso Ultimate which is about 7.5-8.xGB in size? Some time ago my friend asked me to install Win7 on his pc so when I tried to burn it with Fat32 I spent lot of time trying to till then when I decided to go back to the website I downloaded it from and in noticements I saw a tutorial how to burn it which suggested to format usb to `ntfs` ;)

Comment: That is why they recommend a 16GB USB drive for 7.5-8.xGB ISO files.  The limitation is a single continuous file, not the size of the partition.  FAT32 supports up to 16TB partition.  As long as no file in the ISO file is over 4GB, leaving it at FAT32 does not hurt at all.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits

Comment: Yes @Terrance that's what I stated in my answer if the file is over 4GB that's what happened in my case. It was a mod of Win7 which contained such a huge file it was just compressed this way into one big `.exe` and some additional stuff/utilities. ;)

Comment: @JoKeR WOW!  That is a big file.  That's crazy that they would do that.   Most people are not going to have a mod of Win 7 that contains files that large.   But you my friend are definitely correct.

Comment: The content of this answer is indeed correct, but I don't understand from what you deduce that the problem is a big file within the ISO.

Comment: I just wrote what occured in my situation and what I did to solve it... probably there are alternative solutions in the OP case like you suggested using `dd` that can do the trick.