# How to confirm USB Drive is formatted?

Tags: usb-drive, format

I was formatting a USB flash drive, but the Disks Utility window closed after I clicked on Format, and the drive disappeared from locations, so I can't tell if it's done or not. I did the same thing with a flash drive before, and removed it too soon, and got an error, so I don't want to make that mistake again. How do I know if it's finished?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could find some answers here: [How to know when formatting disk has finsihed - Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/962866/how-to-know-when-formatting-disk-has-finsihed-ubuntu-16-04)

Also, you could use `dd` in command line.

Firstly `sudo umount /dev/sd<?>`, then:

`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sd<?> bs=1M status="progress"`

Where `<?>` is the letter corresponding to your USB drive

**NOTE**: To find out the name of your USB drive use `lsblk`.

Another solution can be `gparted`.

Answer (score 0):

Well gnome-disks is a little bit buggy, if you want to quick erase your disk you can do this with cfdisk. 
 cfdisk is extreme stable and works great

Just open a terminal and input `cfdisk` 
Then a console gui should appear. You can control it with your arrow keys. 
Select the partition you want, then delete them and finally click `write` to alter the partition